# MacOS different database from phpmyadmin using command line

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use "mysql" from command line on macos, which works fine. But when i use "show databases" i'm getting only 2 databases, not all the databases that were used with xampp (phpmyadmin).

i add this to the PATH to use mysql :

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH"
```

And when i'm doing this `/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -u root -p` instead of "mysql" it actually worked fine. (i'm getting all the databases).

Is there any way i can get all the databases that are on phpmyadmin using commandline on mac os if that make sense

Comment: what happens when you type 'which mysql' in your terminal?

Comment: Are you always logging in as `root` in both cases?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oh .... I'm stupid .... If i do mysql -u root -p it works ........ thx !

Comment: :) Just remember not all users see all databases, but `root` see's everything